# JSON Countdown Stop at 0 days

Tags: json, sharepoint

I have found a great count down that I'm am using in SharePoint to count down to a date. I have a calculated column that has today + number of days for a task to be complete. at the moment the count down keeps going and show - days and I would like it to stop at 0 days. I don't know if this is possible? any help would be great.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "=floor((Number(@currentField)-Number(Date((getMonth(@now)+1)+'.'+getDate(@now)+'.'+getYear(@now))))/(60*60*24*1000))+' day(s) remaining'"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to display "0 day(s) remaining" when the countdown is less than 0 days, right?

Use this Json code：

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "=if(@currentField>@now,(floor((Number(@currentField)-Number(Date((getMonth(@now)+1)+'.'+getDate(@now)+'.'+getYear(@now))))/(60*60*24*1000))+' day(s) remaining'),'0 day(s) remaining')"
}
```

[image]